# Equivalent function for url.openStream() in Golang

Tags: url, go

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
}
```

I need to do the same in `golang` i.e read and print the html source code, but cannot find the relation between two, I am a beginner with Go language, thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func Error(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    response, err := http.Get("http://www.oracle.com/")
    Error(err)

    defer response.Body.Close()

    contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    Error(err)

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", contents)
}
```

For more details: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/